# regex match between two characters with or condition

Tags: java, regex

I might be thinking of this wrong, but I'm trying to match all things between "_" characters but
I also need the last item (the datetime stamp) Here is the string:

```
StringText_62_590285_20200324082238.xml
```

Here is the regex I have started with (java):

```
\_(.*?)\_
```

but this only matches to: "_62_"

See [here](https://regexr.com/2tr5t)

The result I'm trying to get to is to have 3 matches (62, 590285, 20200324082238)

Now that I'm thinking about this, am I approaching this wrong? This input string is going to be very consistent and maybe just match all strings that are numbers?

Comment: If you’ve got something consistent then just matching numbers would be easier. But if you’re looking to separate based on a character like _ then you’d be better off doing it programmatically with some kind of string.split(“_”) function

Comment: Thanks but in this case I have to use regex. the input text will be very consistent, so you think matching the numbers would be a better approach?

Comment: Yes just a match on (\d+) would be my approach but there are many ways to crack a nut, especially in regex :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example provided, you may use this regex:

```
(?<=_)[^_.]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ikLLTf/1)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `(?<=_)`: Lookbehind to assert that we have a `_` before current position
- `[^_.]+`: Match 1+ of any character that is not a `_` and not a dot

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word boundaries with `_` excluded:

```java
(?<![^\W_])\d+(?![^\W_])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jIZ2lx/1). Details:

- `(?<![^\W_])` - immediately on the left, there can't be a letter or digit
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?![^\W_])` - immediately on the right, there can't be a letter or digit.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/bsBZmd):

```java
String s = "StringText_62_590285_20200324082238.xml";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<![^\\W_])\\d+(?![^\\W_])");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    results.add(matcher.group(0)); 
} 
System.out.println(results);  // => [62, 590285, 20200324082238]
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your example, you can use something like this:

```
(?<=_)(.*?)(?=_|\.)
```

This will basically mean:
Match everything that is preceded by _
and followed by _ or .

Comment: I'd recommend against escaping `_`, it is a *word* char and in some regex flavors, its escaping is even forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

I actually suggest not to use regex in this case but to use two splits, the first split with "_" where you will obtain 4 chunks, you will take the last three and then apply the second split on the last element with "."

Comment: With this approach, there is no guarantee only numbers are extracted.

Answer (score 0):

This regex does the work anyways:

```
\d[0-9]*
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it will also match inside a word, like `98` in `File98.docx`, and the numbers OP needs to extract are in between `_` or within word boundaries.